# Java annotated method - enforce at least one annotated parameter

Tags: java, parameters, annotations, required

I would like to make sure that every method annotated with custom @MyMethod has at least one parameter annotated with @MyParam. Is it possible to enforce compile time, i.e. the below compiles, and without @MyParam in the args it would not compile.

```
@MyMethod
public void someMethod (int x, @MyParam int y) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible if you use [annotation processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html)

Comment: Yes, annotation processing should do it, is anyone willing to provide a sample code snippet?